# How to populate a 2D array with arrays of different lengths so that they are all the same length, in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

In my Ruby script I currently have a 2D array where the elements are all arrays of a differing length. In this example, for simplicity, the integers are the indexes of each respective array and can be thought of as placeholders for the real values which are all strings ..

```
my_2D_array = 
[[1],
[1, 2, 3],
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
[1, 2, 3, 4],
[1, 2],
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
[],
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]
```

How can I populate a new 2D array or manipulate the existing 2D array so that all arrays are the same length, with nil values to fill the new elelements? like this:

```
my_2D_array = 
[[1, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil],
[1, 2, 3, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil],
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, nil],
[1, 2, 3, 4,, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil],
[1, 2, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil],
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, nil, nil, nil, nil],
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil],
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, nil, nil, nil],
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, nil, nil]]
```

Comment: Just to note, I have tried to come up with a solution by researching ruby array-manipulations but while having not found one, my code is very bloated and so I am also looking for nice code abstractions using various tricks in ruby to get something quite modular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
l = my_2D_array.map(&:length).max
my_2D_array.each{|e| e[l - 1] ||= nil}
```

Comment: Did my mind just implode? Yes, yes it did. You are awesome! double thumbs up for being short and modular xD

Comment: clearly an edge case, but `e[l-1] ||= nil` could overwrite `false`

Comment: @Stefan The OP says the values are all strings (or `nil`).

Answer (score 3):

A slightly different way to construct equally sized arrays using [`Array::new`](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-c-new) with a block:

```
size = my_2D_array.map(&:size).max 
my_2D_array.map { |ary| Array.new(size) { |i| ary[i] } }
```

This returns a new array and doesn't modify the nested arrays.

Comment: Awesome! This is very relevant to what I want to achieve in my script! +1 vote once I can upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
max_size = my_2D_array.max_by(&:size).size

my_2D_array.each do |i|
   max_size.times {|j| i[j] = nil if i[j].blank? }
end
```